# Subset HDF5 matrix using values from another submatrix

Tags: r, list, latitude-longitude, subset, hdf5

I have been working with HDF5 files and I have been able to do some subsetting in rhdf5. there are three files:. Longitude, latitude and the ColumnAmountNO2Trop. I have extracted this for all the days in the year as a list in "files".

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".he5", full.names = TRUE)
attribute <- "/HDFEOS/SWATHS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields/ColumnAmountNO2Trop"
attribute2<-"/HDFEOS/SWATHS/ColumnAmountNO2/Geolocation Fields/Longitude"
attribute3<-"/HDFEOS/SWATHS/ColumnAmountNO2/Geolocation Fields/Latitude"
```

and the sub files below:

```
out.list <- lapply(files, h5read, attribute)
Lon <- lapply(files, h5read, attribute2)
Lat<-lapply(files, h5read, attribute3)
```

However, I need to subset out.list(which contains the 'ColumnAmountNO2Trop' for all the days of the year) based on the latitude and longitude values to narrow down my area of reference geographically. I was able to subset them using row and column numbers:

```
lapply(out.list, function(x) x[2:8,2:8])
```

However, the goegraphic location of 2,2 on day one may not be the same on day 2.
I tried to define the Longitude and latitude values to subset with below but it returned an error message.

```
Lond<-c(2,9)
Latd<-c(2,9)
lonKeep <- which(Lon > Lond[1] & Lon < Lond[2])
latKeep <- which(lat> latRan[1] & lat< latRan[2])
```

How do I subset 'out.list' for Lon 2-9 and Lat 2-9, please?

Comment: COuld you add some data?

Comment: Sorry I copied it wrongly initially. I have uploaded sample files here [Link] (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t521gr1rpijmkt9/vuo8Y9tpZw) . I would be working with about 1000 files at the same time soon.

Comment: I think I found a solution. I'll post it soon.

Comment: Can you tell us the ROI ? Where is this place?

Comment: Ok. It is the Niger delta area of Nigeria

Comment: Ok. Perfect. It's the place I'm getting with the raster

Comment: Please, let me know if the approach is valid that we can work the loop over the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find [other approaches](http://www.r-bloggers.com/working-with-hdf-files-in-r-example-pathfinder-sst-data/), possibly with a solution closer to you needs.
An option with hdf5 and raster would be to extract the relevant data from hdf5 files, build a raster, crop it to the ROI and get the values for that area.

I'd do something like this:

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("rhdf5")
library(rhdf5)
library(latticeExtra)

my_wd <- './Stackoverflow/22474417'
files <- list.files(path = my_wd, pattern = ".he5", full.names = F)
files
#[1] "M1.he5" "M2.he5"

attribute <- "/HDFEOS/SWATHS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields/ColumnAmountNO2Trop"
attribute2<- "/HDFEOS/SWATHS/ColumnAmountNO2/Geolocation Fields/Longitude"
attribute3<- "/HDFEOS/SWATHS/ColumnAmountNO2/Geolocation Fields/Latitude"
```

Read a single file

```
m1 <- h5read(file.path(my_wd, files[1]), name = attribute)
dim(m1) # file dimension
# [1] 60 54
prod(dim(m1))
# [1] 3060
```

We'll use it to build a rasterLayer, after extracting the geographical extent from atribute2 and atribute3

```
Lon <- h5read(file.path(my_wd, files[1]) , attribute2)
Lat <- h5read(file.path(my_wd, files[1]) , attribute3)

xmin <- min(Lon[1:prod(dim(m1))]) # Min. Longitude
# [1] -7.141283
xmax <- max(Lon[1:prod(dim(m1))]) # Max. Longitude
ymin <- min(Lat[1:prod(dim(m1))]) # Min. Longitude
ymax <- max(Lat[1:prod(dim(m1))]) # Max. Longitude
```

We can build a raster with the info above

```
m1m <- matrix(m1, nrow = 60)    
m1r <- raster(m1m, xmn = xmin, xmx = xmax,
              ymn =  ymin, ymx = ymax)
```

Take some spatial data to overlay

```
data(wrld_simpl)
spdata <- wrld_simpl[which(wrld_simpl@data$NAME %in% c('Nigeria', 'Cameroon', 'Benin',
                                                       'Togo', 'Ghana',"Cote d'Ivoire",
                                                       'Gabon', 'Equatorial Guinea')), ]
```

From Africa Shoreline 30m

```
delta <- readOGR(dsn = './africa_shoreline_30m',
                 layer = 'nigeria_delta')
```

Build a ROI extent

```
frm <- extent(c(2, 9, 2, 9))
pfrm <- as(frm, 'SpatialPolygons')
```

plot it

```
spplot(m1r,scales = list(draw = TRUE),  ylim=c(-1, 10)) +
  latticeExtra::layer(sp.polygons(stp, fill = NA, col = 'blue'))+
  latticeExtra::layer(sp.polygons(pfrm, fill = NA, col = 'red'))
```

[image: spplot]

Crop and get values from ROI

```
m1rf <- crop(m1r, frm)

spplot(m1rf, scales = list(draw = TRUE), xlim = c(1, 10), ylim=c(1, 10)) +
  latticeExtra::layer(sp.lines(delta, fill = NA, col = 'blue'))+
  latticeExtra::layer(sp.polygons(pfrm, fill = NA, col = 'red'))
```

[image: spplot of ROI]

```
summary(m1rf)
                layer
Min.    -6.528723e+15
1st Qu.  9.437798e+14
Median   1.440395e+15
3rd Qu.  1.896734e+15
Max.     4.232078e+15
NA's     0.000000e+00

m1vals <- getValues(m1rf)
```

Once you agree with this, it's easy to loop over your file folder and get your data.

Comment: Hi Paulo, the approach is valid but isn't it possible to aapproach the data as image  using another package instead of raster in R? This is because the grids are not equal but raster makes them equal. If it isn't possible I would stick with this. Thanks Paulo.

Comment: What if we try the package "fields" which is what I plot images with?

Comment: @JokeO. I've never used but could try. Is this looking good for you? I'm not sure we're getting the correct extents and from first file.

Comment: Oh yes Paulo, it looks good. I would try it all again today using your approach. I change the extent once we have a method.

Comment: Hi Paulo. Thanks. I just went through it and tried using a boundary shapefile to crop in addition to the raster methods above and it worked.